# Database choice for MFC Dekstop Client

Tags: database, database-connection

we have a legacy Windows app written in C++ using the MFC framework. I want to now add capability to communicate with a database at a centralized server. There are ODBC Connection libraries for many of the popular databases which allow me to do exactly what I want (with MySQL for example). But upon further reading, the GPL or LGPL licensing for both the database but more importantly the connection library gets too complicated given my limited legal resources.

Opening up my source code is not an option for me as I am a small operation selling closed source software for profit. My preference is to choose a database with an available connection library with flexible licensing. I don't care if it is free or paid but I'd like it to be something relatively popular with tools, support, some user community, etc.

MySQL seemed simple and widely used but the licensing is a problem for me. The licensing for the PostgreSQL database itself seems much more flexible but the connection library I found is licensed under GPL. Are there perhaps paid options that I'm not aware of?

Should I be considering Microsoft SQL Server?

Can people please recommend any additional options to me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LGPL is what you want. GPL is ambiguous about the status of other works (your code) which links to a GPL library (the ODBC drivers). LGPL purposely is explicit that using a LGPL library does not put your work under LGPL.

Comment: Thanks, your comment helps support my concerns. Any suggestions for a database system that uses LGPL or perhaps less restrictive licensing? I will consider paid software.

Comment: Since the database is a physically separate component there is no way it's licence will affect your software. To get a sensible recommendation you'd have to tell us a lot more: cuncurrentr user count, max throughput, max table size etc. Even t hen it will still probably be off-topic for SE as anyanswer will be 'my preference' based.